# SQL Server 2012 Case Statement Syntax

Tags: sql-server

I have the following case statement where I'm converting a datetime field into YYYYMM and then adding 1 to it. But the data type seems to be a problem.

```
case when convert(varchar(6), max_bdda_open_dt, 112) <= convert(varchar(6), referral_dt, 112) + 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as BDDA_Open
```

When I remove the `+1` and change `<=` to `=` the query runs. I tried changing `varchar` above to `int` but I still get the same error.

The error with the +1 is below. I'm not sure why it says '2014-1' below. When I run the convert statement by itself, my datetimes get converted to 201401 format.

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2014-1' to data type int.
```

Comment: why doesn't it make sense? i'm converting it and adding 1 to it. then applying case logic to create a yes/no field. the conversion works fine on it's own as I mention above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried converting both to int like this:

case when  convert(int, convert(varchar(6), max_bdda_open_dt, 112)) <= convert(int, convert(varchar(6), referral_dt, 112)) + 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as BDDA_Open

that should work

Comment: are the max_bdda_open_dt and referral_dt  datetimes? because i tried the code replacing them both for getdate() and got a 'Yes' output

Comment: Yes they are both datetimes. did you try converting getdate() into yyyymm as above while testing it?

Comment: Thanks. Could you try it with a forced date of Jan. As my post says the error I'm getting is conversion on 2014-1. So it seems like there is a conversion error on single digit months.

Comment: `code`
  DECLARE @max_bdda_open_dt DATE = '20140101',
  @referral_dt DATE= '20140101'
 SELECT case when CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(varchar(6), @max_bdda_open_dt, 112)) <= CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(varchar(6), @referral_dt, 112)) + 1 
  then 'Yes' else 'No' end as BDDA_Open
  --Yes `code`
  `code` DECLARE @max_bdda_open_dt DATE = '20140301',
  @referral_dt DATE= '20140101'
  SELECT case when CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(varchar(6), @max_bdda_open_dt, 112)) <= CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(varchar(6), @referral_dt, 112)) + 1 
  then 'Yes' else 'No' end as BDDA_Open
  --No `code`

Comment: Thanks. I found a data issue that was causing the conversion error. Once I fixed that, your code worked.

Answer (score 1):

No need to convert to character string first.

```
case 
   when cast(max_bdda_open_dt as date) <= dateadd(month, 1, cast(referral_dt as date)) then 'Yes' 
   else 'No' 
end as BDDA_Open
```

If both fields are of datatype `Date` then you can drop the casts.

Comment: I misunderstood the question.  The `varchar(6)` threw me off.

Comment: @MitchWheat I need to add 1 to the YYYYMM format. So if max_bdda_dt gets converted to 201401 and referral_dt gets converted to 201402, I want the case field to say Yes because 201401 <= 201402